# Why does traceback.format_exception require a traceback parameter instead of using ex.__traceback__?

Tags: python, logging

I've been looking at the [traceback module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html), and I'm trying to understand why `format_exception` requires a traceback for the third argument, instead of using `__traceback__`. I tried passing this in my code and it worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traceback module is from before the current exception hierarchy existed. Note that none of the functions make explicit mention of an exception object; they all refer to type, value and traceback. In modern Python, the value is always an exception object, and the other arguments are redundant, but back in ancient versions of Python, exception types could be strings. In that case, you'd raise the exception like

```
raise some_module.exception_string, some_arbitrary_object
```

and `some_arbitrary_object` would be used as the exception value instead of being passed to the exception constructor to create the exception value. You wouldn't have an exception object that you could inspect for the type and traceback, so you'd have to pass all 3 pieces of information around separately.

See the Python 2.0 documentation for [raise](http://docs.python.org/release/2.0/ref/raise.html) and [Guido's article on how exceptions came to be classes](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-exceptions-came-to-be-classes.html) for more details.

Comment: Isn't value an exception object?

Comment: What the - it is. The `sys.exc_info` documentation claims it's the "associated value or the second argument to raise", but if I try `raise Exception, 2`, the value is an `Exception(2,)`, not `2`. What the heck?

Comment: @Casebash: Okay, after digging through some more documentation, I've found sufficiently ancient information to answer the question properly. Also, I think the `sys.exc_info` documentation for modern Python versions needs to be updated.